# Weird behavior in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, css

Can someone tell one why do i get the blue line that i show here: (and also it is really a good practice to define a class for just text-align:center instead of inline code?)

[image: weird behavior]

Code:

```
  <asp:Panel ID="PnlBarraFinalizarMostrar" runat="server" CssClass="izq">
         <asp:LinkButton ID="LkBRegresar" runat="server" CssClass="LKBPequeño" OnClick="LkBRegresar_Click">Regresar</asp:LinkButton>
 </asp:Panel>
                <%--alumn's info--%>
 <asp:Panel ID="PnlAlumno" runat="server" BackColor="Yellow">
       <table runat="server" class="datos" style="background-color:Green;">
             <tr>
                 <td rowspan="4" style="width: 65px;">
                    <asp:Image ID="ImgAlumno" runat="server" BorderWidth="0px"
                                    Width="62.7" Height="84" />
                 </td>
                 <td style="width: 75px;">
                      Alumno:
                 </td>
                 <td style="width:225px; white-space:nowrap;">
                      <asp:Label ID="LbDAlumno" runat="server" />
                 </td>
                 <td style="width: 40px;">
                       Ciclo:
                 </td>
                 <td>
                     <asp:Label ID="LbDciclo" runat="server" />
                 </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td>
                     Carrera:
                 </td>
                 <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="LbDCarrera" runat="server" />
                 </td>
                 <td>
                     Plan:
                 </td>
                 <td>
                     <asp:Label ID="LbDPlan" runat="server" />
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     Maximo UV:
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <asp:Label ID="LbDMaximoUV" runat="server" />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     CUM:
                  </td>
                  <td>
                       <asp:Label ID="LbDCum" runat="server" />
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="vertical-align: text-top; background-color:Gray;">
                     <td>
                         UV Inscritas:
                     </td>
                     <td>
                         <asp:Label ID="LbDUVInscritas" runat="server" />
                     </td>
                     <td>
                          Avance:
                     </td>
                     <td>
                         <asp:Label ID="LbDAvance" runat="server" />
                     </td>
                  </tr>
             </table>
         </asp:Panel>
         <br />
         <%--Detalle de Asignaturas--%>
         <asp:Panel ID="PnlHojaAsesoriaCursosInscritos" runat="server" Width="100%" BackColor="Sienna">                        
               <table class="encabezado">
                    <tr>
                       <td>
                           <asp:Label ID="lbTituloHAsesoriaCInscritos" runat="server" Text="Hoja Asesoria o Cursos Inscritos" />
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                </table>
              <table id="THojaA" runat="server" class="tabla" style="padding:0px;background-color:Red;">
               ...
```

encabezado.css (header)

```
.encabezado 
{
   font-size:10pt;
   text-align:left;
   background-color:#152B81; color:#FFFFFF;   
   border-spacing: 2px;
   padding:3px 4px 2px 5px; 
   width:100%;
}
```

datos.css (data)

```
.datos 
{
 font-size: 9pt;
 border: 1px solid #152B81;
 background-color: #DBE7F6;
 color: #152B81;  
 width: 100%;
 text-align: left;   
 border-spacing:0px;
 padding:4px 4px 4px 5px;
}
```

after using inspection i detect a border-bottom!:

[image]

inspector:

[image]

Comment: Please show us the rendered HTML, not the ASPX controls markup.

Comment: It is hard to say without seeing the entire mark up and css. Does this website available for public currently?

Comment: @Dai you mean the code that see through the 'view HTML code' option in the browser, right?, if that is what you mean it is just more difficult to see the error because i don't know even what section of that code represents what

Comment: @Win this is enough i think because this code is inside a asp:view so the rest is independent, and no this site is for a intranet, is not big deal of a error but i've been redoing their CSS and i just don't know where the hell this line is coming from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use inspect element to check what is happening once the code is parsed. or you can post the parsed html here.

Comment: -1 This is not an answer. If you have question regarding OP, please write as a comment.

Comment: What is OP?, and this was actually useful